# How to return multiple result in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query that check if a `team` is updated. The condition to check the update is: if the field `update_at` of the `team` is greater than 7 days from the current date, then the record need to be updated, eg:

```
id | name     | update_at
67   Tirana     2019-03-06 11:00:12  
68   Partizan   2019-03-06 11:02:04  
69   Lusitanos  2019-03-14 09:00:40

SELECT id
FROM team
WHERE update_at < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND id IN (67, 68, 69);
```

The query works well, in fact the result above is: 67, 68, because the record `69` is already updated (doesn't fit the condition).

Now suppose that the record that I'm looking for doesn't exist in the database, the query will not return it (and this is good), but how can I check if the record need to be added instead of update? eg:

```
id | name     | update_at
67   Tirana     2019-03-06 11:00:12  
68   Partizan   2019-03-06 11:02:04  
69   Lusitanos  2019-03-14 09:00:40

SELECT id
FROM team
WHERE update_at < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND id IN (67, 68, 69, 70);
```

the result is even 67, 68. But contrary to the first example, here the record `70` doesn't exist, so how can I know that using one query?

Is possible return two result such as `record_to_update` and `record_to_add`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` using a derived table or similar logic.  For instance:

```
SELECT tt.team_id
FROM (SELECT 67 as team_id UNION ALL SELECT 68 UNION ALL
      SELECT 69 UNION ALL SELECT 70
     ) tt LEFT JOIN
     team t
     on t.id = tt.team_id AND
        update_at >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
WHERE t.id IS NULL;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=300e1495e5ebd85fba3dfebdaa01cbbe) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want to check `update` versus `insert`, you can do:

```
SELECT tt.team_id,
       (CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 'INSERT'
             ELSE 'UPDATE'
        END) as what_to_do
FROM (SELECT 67 as team_id UNION ALL SELECT 68 UNION ALL
      SELECT 69 UNION ALL SELECT 70
     ) tt LEFT JOIN
     team t
     on t.id = tt.team_id 
WHERE t.id IS NULL OR 
      t.update_at < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77d2325e41e9f5d39780ac53b953a525) is the corresponding db<>fiddle.

By the way, this is an interesting case where `LEFT JOIN` is used, but the filtering on the second table is in the `WHERE` clause, not the `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks for this, just a question: I don't understand if this is another query or is mine improved, because your always return team_id, how can I recognize if the team need to be updated or added?

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . I don't understand your comment.  This answers the question.

Comment: I said: how your query can tell me which record need to be updated and which added?

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . I think you are confused because I left `70` out of the derived table.  I've added a db<>fiddle so you can see it working.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the fiddle, if you look at the result `70` is added but I don't know if this record need to be updated or added because in the table doesn't exists, here there is a misunderstanding

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . Your question would have been clearer if you included desired results.  In any case, I think I understand what you want now and amended the answer.

Comment: is there a way to use `IN` operator instead of have: `SELECT 67 as team_id UNION ALL SELECT 68 UNION ALL
      SELECT 69 UNION ALL SELECT 70` I'm going to use parameterized query and it's difficult to implement this in c#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190148/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-gordon-linoff).

Answer (score 0):

Use another table with IDs and then do a left join between them.