# Correct query not working using MySqlDataReader

Tags: c#, mysql

So I'm trying to figure out of this, in particular I have this query that perfectly works using `PhpMyAdmin`:

```
SELECT tt.team_id, (CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as exist FROM(SELECT 13048 as team_id  UNION ALL SELECT 17058 UNION ALL SELECT 38809 UNION ALL SELECT 8216 UNION ALL SELECT 5466) tt LEFT JOIN team t on t.id = tt.team_id WHERE t.id IS NULL OR t.update_at < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Anyway, I get this error from `Visual Studio`:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' UNION ALL SELECT 17058 UNION ALL SELECT 38809 UNION ALL SELECT 8216 UNION ALL ' at line 1'

This error is retured on:

```
 using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
```

I setup the query in this way:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT tt.team_id, " +
    "(CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as exist " +
    "FROM(SELECT @first as team_id @others) tt LEFT JOIN team t on t.id = tt.team_id " +
    "WHERE t.id IS NULL OR " +
    "t.update_at < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)";

command.Parameters.Add("@first", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = teams.First().Id;
command.Parameters.Add("@others", MySqlDbType.String).Value = string.Concat(teams.Skip(1).Select(c => " UNION ALL SELECT " + c.Id));
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your `@first` and `@others` parameters doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Progman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55196469/how-to-return-multiple-result-in-the-same-query/55196544#55196544

Comment: Parameters are not substitute for sql text, they can be used only to pass values to the database engine.

Comment: You can't use parameterised queries as random string substitution. The parameter is a variable, with a type, not a piece of SQL. The error is because @others was replaced as a string, so it had quotes put round it.

Comment: @iakobski oh my bad, essentially should I include backtick around `UNION ALL SELECT`?

Comment: No, you can't use a parameter to replace the UNION ALL SELECT or whatever SQL statement or table or column name. Just values

Comment: @Steve that's bad, so should I use a foreach or something like that? Did you have a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would build a dynamic list of parameters to pass to your query.
Warning, not tested, but this should produce the expected output

```
// Command text with a placeholder where we insert the dynamic text
string cmd = @"SELECT tt.team_id, 
                      (CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as exist 
               FROM (SELECT {texttoreplace}) tt  
               LEFT JOIN team t on t.id = tt.team_id WHERE t.id IS NULL 
                     OR t.update_at < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)";

int prmCounter = 1;

// Where we keep the text to insert at the appropriate place
StringBuilder unions = new StringBuilder();
// Where we keep the parameters to add at the MySqlCommand
List<MySqlParameter> prms = new List<MySqlParameter>();

// First parameter
MySqlParameter pr = new MySqlParameter("@first", MySqlDbType.Int32) { Value = teams.First().id};
prms.Add(pr);
unions.Append($" @first as team_id ");

// Loop over your IDs and build parameters and text
foreach (var t in teams.Skip(1))
{
    // Giving an unique name to the parameter
    string placeholder = "@p" + prmCounter;
    unions.Append($" UNION ALL SELECT {placeholder}");
    pr = new MySqlParameter(placeholder, MySqlDbType.Int32) { Value = t.id};
    prms.Add(pr);
    prmCounter++;
}
// Add all the required parameters
command.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
// Replace the placeholder with the built text
cmd = cmd.Replace("{texttoreplace}",  unions.ToString());
```